# Why do I get "integer expression required"?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to have a small function that I then call.

To keep it simple I just want to validate that 12 is divisible by 2,3 and 4

The code is:

```
divisible_by () {
  under_test=12
  from=2
  to=4
  divisible=0
  for ((check=from; check<=to; check++)) {
    echo "check= $check"
    if [ $under_test % $check -ne 0 ]; then
      divisible=1
    fi  
  }
  return $divisible
}

x=divisible_by
if [ $x -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

Currently I get

```
./5_divisible_by_1_to_10.sh: line 16: [: 
divisible_by: integer expression expected
false
```

I'm also finding it hard to pass the number in as a parameter but maybe it's related.

Comment: because `$x` is empty. quote it. else it is not a number and you should use `=`. but still - quote it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried "$x" and I also tried "0" for the 0 but still getting the same error...

Comment: Updated lines 8 (`if [ $(($under_test % $check)) -ne 0 ]; then`)

Comment: Now I get  `unary operator expected`

Comment: You get that because the vars you list in `"$((...))"` are not numbers. They need to be numbers *first*. Else you need to *not* expand them before you expand the math. So `"$((var_name))"` not `"$(($var_name))"`.

Comment: See my updated answer, you don't get the function value back that way.

Comment: What language (my guess is a shell, which one). Also the code you posted is not the code that produced the error. Do not do that to us.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant you should roll back your question to the first edition, changing code is invalidating the first part of my answer and makes it very hard for others to follow what is going on. In the original question there were two problems, they should stay there.

Comment: yes I have have flagged it for that (rollback edit). thx.

Comment: I see it has been rolled by mod, but for future: you can rollback yourself whichever post you like (even not necessary yours).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
divisible_by () {
  under_test=12
  from=2
  to=4
  for ((check=from; check<=to; check++)) {
    echo "check=$check"
    ((under_test % check == 0)) || return
  }
  true
}

if divisible_by; then
  echo true
else
  echo false
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the line:

```
  if [ $under_test % $check -ne 0 ]; then
```

into

```
  if [ "$(($under_test % $check))" -ne 0 ]; then
```

without that the test (`[`) gives the too many arguments.

What I did to find this is just run the program:

```
under_test=12
from=2
to=4
divisible=0
for ((check=from; check<=to; check++)) {
  echo "check= $check"
  if [ $under_test % $check -ne 0 ]; then
    divisible=1
  fi  
}
```

and get that to work correct first.

The other problem is returning a value from a function:

```
divisible_by () {
  under_test=12
  from=2
  to=4
  divisible=0
  for ((check=from; check<=to; check++)) {
    echo "check= $check"
    if [ "$(($under_test % $check))" -ne 0 ]; then
      divisible=1
    fi  
  }
  mydivisible=$divisible
}

divisible_by
x=$mydivisible
if [ "$x" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

As return doesn't return the function value.

Running that gives the output:

```
check= 2
check= 3
check= 4
true
```

Answer (score 0):

`x=divisible_by` won't call the `divisible_by` function. What you can do is either

```
divisible_by
x=$?
```

(but this is a bad way to do in case of `set -e`), or

```
divisible_by () {
[...]
echo $divisible
}

x=$(divisible_by)
[...]
```

Comment: `set -e` is usually a bad way to do most things in any sense that means it is universally applied.

Comment: `set -e` is often necessary, otherwise you must check whether an error occurred after most command execution.

Comment: `set -e` is not a good substitute for well-planned and securely written code. If commands are chained in such a way that the results you want are the only ones you can get, `set -e` is irrelevant.

Comment: This is nonsense. Look at the many scripts using `set -e`.

Comment: I have seen many - and it is not nonsense. *Many* does not translate to *good*. `set -e` should be used for a specific purpose - so for example if it is a way for you to arrive at the results you want and no other it is well used. If it is instead a used in a way intended to avoid tests then it is a bug.

Comment: Again, nonsense. If you think that it is a bug, then report a bug.